# Can a character use "provoke" repeatedly to defeat monsters?

Tags: fate-core, stress, conflicts

In FATE Core there are two types of combat: physical and mental. The mechanics are more or less the same: the **physical combat uses fight or shoot against fight or athletics**, while **mental combat uses provoke against will**.

Most monsters are stronger in physical combat than mental combat. So, if a character is strong in "provoke", it seems that he can use that to simply scare away every enemy or monster in his way.

Is that true? Am I missing something?

Comment: You are severely limiting your options about conflicts here. In a conflict, every skill is usable, and every stress track is fair game as long as it makes story sense. You can use *shoot* to scare your opponent into submission, or *provoke* him into making a tactical mistake so that he gets caught in the crossfire. If the situation warrants it, you can *drive* and run someone over, or buy their wits out with immense expenditure of *resources*. Always remember [the golden rule](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/what-do-during-play#the-golden-rule)

Answer (score 2):

The main thing is that in order for Provoke to work, you've got to establish in the fiction that the monster is capable of being manipulated that way. Goblins are cowardly, and wolves are more interested in food than slaughter most of the time, but it's possible that zombies or orcs have Aspects or other qualities that make them harder or impossible to Provoke in certain ways even if they have low Will.